# How to rearrange View fields in different order

Tags: 7, views, entities

I have a View with 4 rows & 2 columns. Each item is composed of an image & title. The left column needs an image on top & title on bottom,
the right column needs to invert that order.

How can I do that for 2 different fields?

Left Column Order:
[image: order for the left column]

Right Column Order:
[image]

Is this possible with views?